# ChartJs in endless loop

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I've got a just-created empty chart.js chart and it stucks in an animated endless loop. Why? What am I doing wrong?

```js
var initData=
{
  type: "polarArea",
  data: {datasets:[]},
  options: {
    plugins: {},
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scales: {
      r: {}
    }
  }
};

var context = document.getElementById('test').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(context, initData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.5.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.0.0"></script>
<div><canvas style="margin: 0.5em; width: 100%; height: 20em" id="test"></canvas></div>
```

Comment: Just a guess, that is a demo mode if you do not give any data to the chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to happen because chart.js does not like the small amount of margin, if you increase it it works fine or if you put a surrounding div around it and put the margin on that it also seems to work fine:

```js
var initData = {
  type: "polarArea",
  data: {
    labels: ['a', 'b'],
    datasets: [{
      data: [2, 4]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {},
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scales: {
      r: {}
    }
  }
};

var context = document.getElementById('test').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(context, initData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.5.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.0.0"></script>

<div>
  <div style="margin: 0.5em;">
    <canvas style="width: 100%; height: 20em;" id="test"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:**
I was not totally correct with the larger size of margin fixes it, it so happend to just be a correct number.

Chart.js does need a dedicated container around the chart for the margin to function properly as described in the docs [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/configuration/responsive.html#:%7E:text=%3Ccanvas%20style%3D%22margin%3A%200%20auto%3B%22%3E%3A%20invalid%20behavior%2C%20the%20canvas%20continually%20shrinks.%20Chart.js%20needs%20a%20dedicated%20container%20for%20each%20canvas%20and%20this%20styling%20should%20be%20applied%20there.)

Comment: Huhh, thanks, it solved. But shouldn't it be treated as a chartjs bug anyway? Is it wort opening an issue...?

Comment: No I was wrong, just got a number of margin it didnt happen for, in the docs its also specified that this behaviour will occur and you will need to use a separate wrapper div on which you apply the styling